# Where is the definition of one-way trap-door function used in public key cryptography

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, one-way-function, trapdoor

This is a rather simple question but I've been unable to find a proper answer for this online.

When defining an asymmetric (public key) algorithm is the one-way trap-door function usage referring to the encryption/decryption function or the key generation process or perhaps both?

I believe that the one-way function is indeed used in the key generation process, but I'm not sure entirely.

For instance when we look upon Diffie-Hellman and RSA, it is known that RSA uses integer factorization as its one-way trap-door, meanwhile Diffie-Hellman uses discrete logarithms.

Comment: Usually you do not find much definition of the trapdoor within the definition of the encryption scheme. You might come across it in this form "assuming a function X with the hardness assumption Y ..." But its exact properties play a role in the security proof - the definition just assumes, it exists.

Comment: That's my issue I guess. I expect everything to be defined precisely, as for me without such definitions there is no proper science. Like, in asymmetric cryptography things are literally all over the place in terms of definitions and norms. You can't find proper literature that could give an exact definition of basic things.

Comment: What is the issue? The in-depth analysis does not belong into the definition. A clear structure usually makes things easier to differentiate and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliptic curve cryptography (ECC) does not use a one-way trapdoor function. It uses a homomorphically-additive one-way function which transforms a private key into a public key. "Trapdoor" is not a synonym for "one-way" or "invertible". Trapdoor means a function that can be used without knowledge of the "trapdoor" secret, and inverted only with knowledge of the secret.

You can't directly encrypt or decrypt with ECC. You can only agree a key (using Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman), and then use that key for symmetric encryption/decryption. Signatures are achieved using a chameleon-hash function, which has a trapdoor (the private key) that can be used to find collisions in order to produce a valid signature that no one else would be able to produce. This is entirely different from the RSA trapdoor function, which allows the trapdoor function to be used in one direction without any secret knowledge, but can be inverted with knowledge of the trapdoor secret.

RSA uses a one-way trapdoor function. The private key (the trapdoor knowledge) and public key are created together from two secret primes when a key pair is generated. The trapdoor function is not used to create the key pair - it's the other way around. Generating the key pair provides the parameters for the trapdoor function. You can directly encrypt with RSA, because there is trapdoor information available that can directly reverse the encryption process. You can also directly sign, by "encrypting" with the private key something that anyone can "decrypt" with the public key.

Summary:

For DH, you choose a private key, and you calculate the public key using $f(x)=g^x\ mod\ p$, where the input is the private key and $g$ is a well-known generator. This is not a trapdoor function, because although the inverse function is $f^{-1}(y)=y^{x^{-1}}\ mod\ p$ (where $x^{-1}$ is the modular inverse of $x$), the secret needs to be known both for $f$ and for $f^{-1}$. The definition of a trapdoor function is that the secret trapdoor information is only required when going in one direction.

For ECDH, you choose a private key, and you calculate the public key using $f(x)=xG$, where the $xG$ operation is scalar multiplication of the scalar $x$ with the well-known generator point $G$. For the same reason as before, this is not a trapdoor function.

For RSA, the keygen is to pick a public key $e$, pick two secret primes $p$ and $q$, and then calculate the private exponent $d$ which can only be calculated with knowledge of $p$ and $q$ ($p$ and $q$ are then discarded, and we only retain the modulus $n=pq$). The one-way trapdoor function is $f(x)=x^e\ mod\ n$, and the secret knowledge to invert the trapdoor function is $d$. This allows us to use the inverse function $f^{-1}(y)=y^d\ mod\ n$. Unlike DH and EC, we can't re-determine the public key from the private key if we lose the public key exponent $e$.

Comment: Dlog is a trapdoor function in EC. The additive notation is just that: notation. If you want, you could call it "discrete multiplicative", which works just like dlog.

Comment: @tylo The definition of a trapdoor function is that it is reversible with knowledge of the trapdoor. This definition does not apply to EC scalar multiplication - it is one-way but not a trapdoor function.

Comment: @tylo also see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/835/why-cant-diffie-hellman-be-used-for-signing/838#838 "Most asymmetric encryption algorithms are not trapdoor permutations"

Comment: And in pkc systems with dlog hardness, this is achieved by knowing the dlog of some element. Knowledge of that allows DH, Elgamal, etc. to work. DLOG itself is not a part of any algorithm to rncrypt, decrypt, sign, etc.

Comment: ECDH is based on DH and DH exists only because of the discrete logarithm problem, as far as I know. Since all parameters are publicly known, before the key exchange commences, if the attacker can solve a discrete logarithm for strong group parameters (2048 bit size multiplicative group and an okay generator), they break the algorithm. I wanted to say that this algorithm is indeed a one-way trap-door function, but not in the key agreement part of the algorithm, instead in the key generation part (where the public DH keys are generated, since both the private and public key are bound together).

Comment: Trapdoor means that you can apply a function to an input, and then do the reverse and get from the output back to the input with knowledge of the trapdoor. Scalar multiplication does not meet this test. If you disagree with me, you're also disagreeing with [Thomas Pornin](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/838/43864)

Comment: @tylo yes I've seen the post that you mentioned, but really the difference is that RSA and DH/ECDH are different algorithms that shouldn't be seen in the same light - RSA can do public key encryption, meanwhile DH can only do key exchange (if you count out schemes based on DH that enable this - ElGamal for instance).

Comment: @tylo this comes down to one question - what is the trap-door one-way function used in RSA? Is it integer prime factorization or modular exponentiation? I have seen multiple definitions of trap-door one-way functions in literature and both meet the same requirements. So are both of them one-way trap-doors or am I missing something out? This is the most confusing point for me when understanding asymmetric cryptography, since the encryption process can only be reversed by using the correct private key, meanwhile both the private and public key must be tied mathematically,

Comment: @CryptoNewbie Modular exponentiation in traditional DH (and the equivalent scalar multiplication in ECDH) are not reversible and not trapdoor functions. But, with RSA, because you know both of the primes, you can reverse the modular exponentiation with one of the primes with knowledge of the other prime. That's why DH and RSA are different even though they both involve modular exponentiation.

Comment: @tylo but isn't the discrete logarithm problem just an inversion of the modular exponentiation? It's the discrete logarithm problem that the attacker has to solve in order to attack algorithms based on it.

Comment: @CryptoNewbie "what is the trap-door one-way function used in RSA?" It is modular exponentiation, with a modulus and prime exponent chosen such that the function cannot be reversed without knowledge of the other prime exponent.

Comment: @knaccc sorry if I misunderstood something, but for instance if we consider the simpler DH modular exponentiation, someone can indeed reverse it if the private key is known, how ever this property isn't used, because it's a key exchange algorithm, rather than a public key encryption algorithm. In other words, the function which is used in the key generation algorithm, which produces the public key with the corresponding private key can be reversed by using the same private key, which is by definition a one-way trap-door function.

Comment: @CryptoNewbie The definition of a trapdoor one-way function is that you need to know the secret information only when going backwards. You need the public to be able to use the function forwards without knowledge of the secret, otherwise they would be able to use the function in both directions. And yes, with DH you start with a private key, compute the public key from it, and then exchange public keys as part of the DH key agreement. This is different from RSA, where you generate both the private and public moduli together as part of key generation.

Comment: This is basically the core of my initial question - can both key generation algorithms, as well as encryption and decryption ones, be considered as one-way trap-door functions? Keep in mind that both of them are critical for the proper security of an asymmetric algorithm.

Comment: @CryptoNewbie DH public key generation from the private key does not use a trapdoor one-way function, it uses a one-way function. The RSA trapdoor function is one whose parameters are decided during the key generation, it's not the other way around. A member of the public (or the private key holder that has lost their public RSA exponent) cannot try and apply a trapdoor function to a private RSA exponent in order to get the public RSA exponent. But anyone can transform a DH private key to the corresponding DH public key, or transform an EC private key to the corresponding EC public key.

Comment: @CryptoNewbie This is why with DH or EC, you only need to remember the private key, and you can re-determine the corresponding public key at any time. With RSA, if you keep the private exponent and lose the public exponent, you can't re-determine the public exponent (unless you kept the other workings from the key gen process that are normally discarded).

Comment: @knaccc Thanks for your replies, but I'm still a bit confused. I'll think about this later.

Comment: @CryptoNewbie I added some further explanation to the answer

Comment: @knaccc Oh I understood your point 100% now with the added explanation. Everything is clear now, I missed that the secret is actually also needed in the public key generation algorithm and  that this goes against the one-way trap-door definition. Thanks again for your help.